# Flink: possible to delete Queryable state after X time?

Tags: java, scala, hdfs, apache-flink, flink-streaming

In my case, I use Flink's queryable state only. In particular, I do not care about checkpoints.

Upon an event, I query the queryable state only after a maximum of X minutes. Ideally, I would delete the "old" state to save on space.

That's why I wonder: can I signal Flink's state to clear itself after some time? Through configuration? Through specific event signals? How?

Answer (score 2):

One way to clear state is to explicitly call `clear()` on the state object (e.g., a ValueState object) when you no longer need it for a particular key. This is typically done in an `onTimer()` callback in a `ProcessFunction`.

Another possible approach would be to use [state time-to-live](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/stream/state/state.html#state-time-to-live-ttl) to manage its lifecycle.

I haven't tried using state TTL with queryable state, but I can't see any reason why it shouldn't work. However, as of Flink 1.7, state TTL only actually clears state (for a key) when the state is accessed (for that key), or when taking a full state snapshot. So in your particular case, this state TTL mechanism may not be very useful.

Comment: I actually need to check the value only ONCE, so TTL, if I understood you correctly, might be perfect for my needs! I report tomorrow -- Can you point me to the documentation about `clear()` and `onTimer()`? I don't quite know what you mean by "state object". I'm just defining my `QueryableStateStream` with `asQueryableState`

Comment: clear() is something that can be called on a ValueState, ListState, etc. object in the processElement() or onTimer() method of a ProcessFunction. See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/stream/state/state.html#using-managed-keyed-state and https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/stream/operators/process_function.html.

Comment: Thank you for your hints @David Anderson. Ideally I would use `clear()` from the `QueryableStateClient` (right after reading the value once). I understand that is currently not possible; when I attempt to use the method from the client I receive a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: State is read-only. No modifications allowed`. Probably that's one possible feature request. ---- I will try my luck with a timer or TTL and report back.

Comment: The clear() can only be done in the operator that has the state, which is in the job serving the state, not the client.

Comment: Unfortunately (`Flink 1.6` and I believe `Flink 1.7` too) explicitly doesn't support TTL for queryable state. This is what I get: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Queryable state is currently not supported with TTL`.

Comment: I'm not so sure about using timers either because in my application that would create way too many timers, which I guess would defeat the purpose of saving on memory. As per my use case, it totally makes sense to just clear the value of the queryable state as soon as it's read once. I can raise this issue if you think it appropriate.

Comment: Yep, the current lack of support of TTL for queryable state is well known: http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Queryable-state-and-state-TTL-td22642.html