# Flink: QueryableStateClient unresponsive after a while

Tags: java, scala, hdfs, apache-flink, flink-streaming

In my Flink application, I rely on Flink's Queryable state to query for computation results.

Unfortunately, after a while of running the application and receiving many computation requests, the query client dies (it's not anymore responsive). I have debugged this for a long while but cannot figure why this happens.

Do you have any hints, as of why **`QueryableStateClient`** dies?

Is **`RocksDBStateBackend`** the solution to the problem? Is **`RocksDBStateBackend`** preferred in production although perhaps a bit slower?

---

My stack is:

- `Flink 1.6.2`
- My level of parallelism/threads is > 1
- I'm either using the `MemoryStateBackend` or `FsStateBackend` state backends. I haven't tested yet with the `RocksDBStateBackend`. I'm aware of the following caveat, but supposedly `RocksDBStateBackend` is slower?

  > read-modify-write patterns are unsafe and may cause the queryable state server to fail due to concurrent modifications. The RocksDBStateBackend is safe from these issues.
- With `FsStateBackend`, I have tried both a local file system and a hdfs. Both fail.
- I've also asked [Flink: possible to delete Queryable state after X time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54330034/flink-possible-to-delete-queryable-state-after-x-time) to figure out whether "too much" state is the problem.

Comment: The task manager logs for the job with the queryable state client should provide some clues about why it died.

Comment: When I was debugging something similar, I ran the queryable state client in my IDE, which was very helpful.

Comment: It's very easy to set up the RocksDBStateBackend. Why not give it a try?

Comment: The logs didn't tell me anything -- I will report tomorrow using the `RocksDBStateBackend` -- Thanks!